# Clickable ImageView over List view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

i have a app that has a listview. I want to place a imageview over part of the listview. When i set the onclick Listener for the imageview nothing happens. How do i make it so that the imageview is clickable and not the area of the listview that overlaps with the imageview.

the imageview "id/imagemenu" should be clickable
xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 <RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagemenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

    android:src="@drawable/menub" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/header" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/camerab" />

 </RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you show us your xml ?

Comment: ok i have posted my xml code

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add selector, check this out.

```
<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/imageButton"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/selector" />
```

The corresponding selector file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ico_100_checked" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ico_100_unchecked"/>
</selector>
```

And in my onCreate I call:

```
final ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) value.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

OnClickListener ocl =new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View button) {
        if (button.isSelected()){
            button.setSelected(false);
        } else {
            ib.setSelected(false);
            //put all the other buttons you might want to disable here...
            button.setSelected(true);
        }
    }
};

ib.setOnClickListener(ocl);
//add ocl to all the other buttons
```

Hope this helps.